# UITableView Add button on new cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Im trying to add a button into a new cell in a tableview, for example, I need a button under cell '1' if dim is not 0.

However I'm unable to do it. Please enlighten me.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        _displaynum = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3", nil];
        _displayID = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ID = 1",@"ID = 2",@"ID = 3", nil];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

        return [_displaynum count];

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

        static NSString *lightIdentifier = @"lightIdentifier";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:lightIdentifier];


        if (cell == nil){
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:lightIdentifier];
        }
        UISwitch *switchLights = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(1.0, 1.0, 20.0, 20.0)];
        cell.textLabel.text = [_displayLights objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =[_displayLightsID objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryView = switchLights;
        switchLights.on = NO;
        int dim = 1;
        if ((dim =! 0)) {
            NSArray *insertIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
                                 nil];
            NSArray *deleteIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],nil];

            [tableView beginUpdates];
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [tableView endUpdates];
        }

        return cell;
     }



    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is not the right place to insert or delete rows the way you are doing.

`cellForRowAtIndexPath:` gets called every time a new cell is drawn by iOS. So, this is the place where you can modify your cells and simply return it.

That said, this is what you need to do:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *lightIdentifier = @"lightIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:lightIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:lightIdentifier];
    }

    int dim = 1;

    if (dim != 0 && indexPath.row == 1) {
        CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(210, 25, 65, 25);
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.frame = buttonRect;
        // set the button title here if it will always be the same
        [button setTitle:@"Action" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.tag = 1;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on tableView, I have come close to the result. But the button seems to be overlay with the 2nd cell.

Comment: You need to adjust the button frame based on your cell height. You can also increase the cell height. Let me know if you need any help there.

Comment: I understand about the button frame, but the button has overlay with the 2nd object to be exact. For exp, cell 1( Object 1), button, cell 2( Object 2). Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry but I did not get you. You mean on cell 1 itself, button overlaps with another object in same cell (cell 1)?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7d5NfWuctgfbTQwTDdBQkRieHc/view?usp=sharing

Sorry, i cant post the picture here. So I will share it thru the gdrive. Sorry again

Comment: Not able to open this link.

Comment: The button I have created was in the same cell with the second array of table view, where the overlay occurs. I'm trying to locate the button in a new cell under the first array, and following with second array.